# getListenerList or getListeners

Tags: java, javabeans, event-listener

I'm curious about which method should be used to retrieve the list of listeners from an EventListenerList. The Oracle docs example shows getListenerList and then traversing backwards through it in the fireXXXEvent method, but I'm wondering if getListeners would be a better choice?

```
     listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
     for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
```

or

```
     listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ListenerClass.class);
     for (ListenerClass listener : listeners) {
```

Comment: What do you mean "EventList"? There are several different libraries that use that class name, might want to clarify.

Comment: corrected and added samples

Answer (score 1):

If all your Listeners are of a single, known class, the second form is much simpler and less prone to error.  If you have maybe two types of listeners, use the second form twice.

If you have a mish-mash of listeners of different classes, use the first form, which IMO is some of the ugliest, grossest, hackiest, least Object Oriented code ever written.

p.s.  IMO (admittedly biased cause I really dislike the EventListenerList implementation) you should consider writing your own EventListenerList class using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` or `CopyOnWriteArraySet`, which are ideally suited for this task.

Comment: You've lead a sheltered programming life.

Comment: So, there's no performance reason for going with the first form?

Comment: The difference in performance in actually sending the events should be minimal.  Performance issues in handling events happen when the Listeners take too long, have issues with the EDT, trigger several new cascades of events (that trigger new cascades...), are called multiple times, or create infinite loops.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin Sure, I'm overreacting, but for the Java "gurus" to expose this loop by -2 and check for class== on the odds and cast the listener on the evens as a "recommended" technique really irks me.